# first chern class

Tags: algebraic-geometry, complex-geometry

If $M$ is a Fano manifold, and $K_M$ is the canonical line bundle of $M$. If $L$ is an ample line bundle over $M$, and $c_1(L)=\lambda c_1(M)$, for some positive number $\lambda$. What is the relation of $L$ and $-K_M$? Of course, if $M$ is $\mathbb{CP}^n$, this is clear for $\lambda\in Z^+$, how about other cases? Furthermore, what is the relation of the divisors with respect to $L$ and $-K_M$?

Comment: For Fano manifolds, line bundles are completely determined by their first Chern class. So if $c_1(L)=\lambda c_1(M) = \lambda c_1(-K_M)$, then if $\lambda$ is an integer we get $L = (-K_M)^{\otimes \lambda}$; if $\lambda^{-1}$ is an integer, then $L^{\otimes \lambda} = -K_M$.

Comment: Would you like to give me some reference for this result?

Comment: Is it true for $\lambda$ not an integer or a rational number?

Comment: The Picard group is a finitely generated abelian group. If one of these line bundles is a multiple of another, it is a rational multiple.

Comment: OK! Thank you! Would you like to give me some reference for your first answer? Because I am a newer of algebraic geometry, I do not know where I can find this answer.

Comment: Dear Daniel, I am not sure of a good reference. Maybe try Chapter 1 of Griffiths--Harris, _Principles of Algebraic Geometry_.